# XML element dynamic in xquery

Tags: xquery

My text file is EDI format:

```
    UNB+UNOA:1+5013546126405::CCC+5016237006116+160729:1253+00952177'UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN'BGM+230:::Purchase Order Change V201+1911677::0+5+AB'DTM+137:201607291253:203'DTM+4:201606150000:203'DTM+154:201608080000:203'RFF+CT:XXXX/0140'NAD+VN++XXX HOUSE:XXXX CLOSE::XXX+XX XX XX XX LIMITED++XXX+:162::United Kingdom+XX 0XX'LOC+80+:::U3F36'CTA+CW'COM+N/A:TE'NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom'NAD+BT++XX XX IP:XX HOUSE,:XX XX,:XX+++XX,+:162::United Kingdom+XX XXX'LOC+2+:::XXXXX'NAD+BY++XX XX XX:XX HOUSE:XX XX:XX+++XX+:162::UnitedKingdom+XXX XXXX'LOC+158+:::XXXXXX'RFF+VA'CTA+OC+:XX XX'COM+01593424302:TE'CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) XXX'COM+01600 711338:TE'CUX+2:GBP'PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate'LIN+1++:VN'PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN'PIA+5+1117394:AU'IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk'IMD+C++:20'MEA+ABA+:::EACH'QTY+21:3:EA'QTY+169:3:EA'QTY+182:0:EA'QTY+194:0:EA'QTY+256:0:EA'DTM+2:201606170000:203'MOA+128:30.54'MOA+146:10.18'FTX+LIN'RFF+ON:1911677'RFF+FI:1/1'RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1'RFF+ADE:PKE00'NAD+ST++XX XX XX XX:XX XX, XX XX,:XXX+++XXXX+:162::United Kingdom+XXX XXX'LOC+8+:::A3101A'CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header'UNS+S'UNT+46+02585706'UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN'BGM+230:::Purchase Order ChangeV201+1911677::0+5+AB'DTM+137:201607291253:203'DTM+4:201606150000:203'DTM+154:201608080000:203'RFF+CT:ZZZZ/0140'NAD+VN++ZZZ HOUSE:ZZZZ CLOSE::ZZZ+ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ LIMITED++ZZZ+:162::United States+ZZ 0ZZ'LOC+80+:::U3F36'CTA+CW'COM+N/A:TE'NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom'NAD+BT++ZZ ZZ IP:ZZ HOUSE,:ZZ ZZ,:ZZ+++ZZ,+:162::United Kingdom+ZZ ZZZ'LOC+2+:::ZZZZZ'NAD+BY++ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ HOUSE:ZZ ZZ:ZZ+++ZZ+:162::UnitedKingdom+ZZZ ZZZZ'LOC+158+:::ZZZZZZ'RFF+VA'CTA+OC+:ZZ ZZ'COM+01593424302:TE'CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) ZZZ'COM+01600 711338:TE'CUZ+2:GBP'PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate'LIN+1++:VN'PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN'PIA+5+1117394:AU'IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk'IMD+C++:20'MEA+ABA+:::EACH'QTY+21:3:EA'QTY+169:3:EA'QTY+182:0:EA'QTY+194:0:EA'QTY+256:0:EA'DTM+2:201606170000:203'MOA+128:30.54'MOA+146:10.18'FTZ+LIN'RFF+ON:1911677'RFF+FI:1/1'RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1'RFF+ADE:PKE000'NAD+ST++ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ ZZ, ZZ ZZ,:ZZZ+++ZZZZ+:162::United Kingdom+ZZZ ZZZ'LOC+8+:::A3101A'CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header'UNS+S'UNT+46+02585706'UNZ+1+00952177'
```

I want to get the result from xquery as below:

```
    <Segment>
      <UNB>UNB+UNOA:1+5013546126405::CCC+5016237006116+160729:1253+00952177</UNB>
      <UNH>UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN</UNH>
      <BGM>BGM+230:::Purchase Order Change V201+1911677::0+5+AB</BGM>
      <DTM>DTM+137:201607291253:203</DTM>
      <DTM>DTM+4:201606150000:203</DTM>
      <DTM>DTM+154:201608080000:203</DTM>
      <RFF>RFF+CT:XXXX/0140</RFF>
      <NAD>NAD+VN++XXX HOUSE:XXXX CLOSE::XXX+XX XX XX XX LIMITED++XXX+:162::United Kingdom+XX 0XX</NAD>
      <LOC>LOC+80+:::U3F36</LOC>
```

I am trying to write xquery but it is giving me error, could anyone please advice me how to resolve the error:

```
    <Segment>{ for $id in fn:tokenize(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($body,""),"UNZ"),"'")
     let $x := fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($id,""),"+")
     return
     element {$x} {$id} }
    </Segment>
```

error:

```
    Error executing the transformation: Error parsing XML: {err}XP0021: "": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}QName: error: Invalid QName value: Localname not a valid NCName in ''
```

I tried in two steps,
stored below result in variable

```
    <Segment>{ for $id in fn:tokenize(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($body,""),"UNZ"),"'")
     return
     <token>{$id}</token> }
    </Segment>
```

The ouput of variable will be

```
    <Segment>
<token>
UNB+UNOA:1+5013546126405::CCC+5016237006116+160729:1253+00952177
</token>
<token>UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN</token>
<token>
BGM+230:::Purchase Order Change V201+1911677::0+5+AB
</token>
<token>DTM+137:201607291253:203</token>
<token>DTM+4:201606150000:203</token>
<token>DTM+154:201608080000:203</token>
<token>RFF+CT:XXXX/0140</token>
<token>
NAD+VN++XXX HOUSE:XXXX CLOSE::XXX+XX XX XX XX LIMITED++XXX+:162::United Kingdom+XX 0XX
</token>
<token>LOC+80+:::U3F36</token>
<token>CTA+CW</token>
<token>COM+N/A:TE</token>
<token>NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom</token>
<token>
NAD+BT++XX XX IP:XX HOUSE,:XX XX,:XX+++XX,+:162::United Kingdom+XX XXX
</token>
<token>LOC+2+:::XXXXX</token>
<token>
NAD+BY++XX XX XX:XX HOUSE:XX XX:XX+++XX+:162::UnitedKingdom+XXX XXXX
</token>
<token>LOC+158+:::XXXXXX</token>
<token>RFF+VA</token>
<token>CTA+OC+:XX XX</token>
<token>COM+01593424302:TE</token>
<token>CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) XXX</token>
<token>COM+01600 711338:TE</token>
<token>CUX+2:GBP</token>
<token>PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate</token>
<token>LIN+1++:VN</token>
<token>PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN</token>
<token>PIA+5+1117394:AU</token>
<token>
IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk
</token>
<token>IMD+C++:20</token>
<token>MEA+ABA+:::EACH</token>
<token>QTY+21:3:EA</token>
<token>QTY+169:3:EA</token>
<token>QTY+182:0:EA</token>
<token>QTY+194:0:EA</token>
<token>QTY+256:0:EA</token>
<token>DTM+2:201606170000:203</token>
<token>MOA+128:30.54</token>
<token>MOA+146:10.18</token>
<token>FTX+LIN</token>
<token>RFF+ON:1911677</token>
<token>RFF+FI:1/1</token>
<token>RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1</token>
<token>RFF+ADE:PKE00</token>
<token>
NAD+ST++XX XX XX XX:XX XX, XX XX,:XXX+++XXXX+:162::United Kingdom+XXX XXX
</token>
<token>LOC+8+:::A3101A</token>
<token>CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header</token>
<token>UNS+S</token>
<token>UNT+46+02585706</token>
<token>UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN</token>
<token>
BGM+230:::Purchase Order ChangeV201+1911677::0+5+AB
</token>
<token>DTM+137:201607291253:203</token>
<token>DTM+4:201606150000:203</token>
<token>DTM+154:201608080000:203</token>
<token>RFF+CT:ZZZZ/0140</token>
<token>
NAD+VN++ZZZ HOUSE:ZZZZ CLOSE::ZZZ+ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ LIMITED++ZZZ+:162::United States+ZZ 0ZZ
</token>
<token>LOC+80+:::U3F36</token>
<token>CTA+CW</token>
<token>COM+N/A:TE</token>
<token>NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom</token>
<token>
NAD+BT++ZZ ZZ IP:ZZ HOUSE,:ZZ ZZ,:ZZ+++ZZ,+:162::United Kingdom+ZZ ZZZ
</token>
<token>LOC+2+:::ZZZZZ</token>
<token>
NAD+BY++ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ HOUSE:ZZ ZZ:ZZ+++ZZ+:162::UnitedKingdom+ZZZ ZZZZ
</token>
<token>LOC+158+:::ZZZZZZ</token>
<token>RFF+VA</token>
<token>CTA+OC+:ZZ ZZ</token>
<token>COM+01593424302:TE</token>
<token>CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) ZZZ</token>
<token>COM+01600 711338:TE</token>
<token>CUZ+2:GBP</token>
<token>PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate</token>
<token>LIN+1++:VN</token>
<token>PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN</token>
<token>PIA+5+1117394:AU</token>
<token>
IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk
</token>
<token>IMD+C++:20</token>
<token>MEA+ABA+:::EACH</token>
<token>QTY+21:3:EA</token>
<token>QTY+169:3:EA</token>
<token>QTY+182:0:EA</token>
<token>QTY+194:0:EA</token>
<token>QTY+256:0:EA</token>
<token>DTM+2:201606170000:203</token>
<token>MOA+128:30.54</token>
<token>MOA+146:10.18</token>
<token>FTZ+LIN</token>
<token>RFF+ON:1911677</token>
<token>RFF+FI:1/1</token>
<token>RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1</token>
<token>RFF+ADE:PKE000</token>
<token>
NAD+ST++ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ ZZ, ZZ ZZ,:ZZZ+++ZZZZ+:162::United Kingdom+ZZZ ZZZ
</token>
<token>LOC+8+:::A3101A</token>
<token>CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header</token>
<token>UNS+S</token>
<token>UNT+46+02585706</token>
<token/>
</Segment>
```

from that variable i called another xquery

```
    <Segment>{ for $id in $body//token/text()
    let $x := fn:substring-before($id,"+")
    return
    element {$x} {$id} }
    </Segment>
```

final output

```
    <Segment>
<UNB>
UNB+UNOA:1+5013546126405::CCC+5016237006116+160729:1253+00952177
</UNB>
<UNH>UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN</UNH>
<BGM>
BGM+230:::Purchase Order Change V201+1911677::0+5+AB
</BGM>
<DTM>DTM+137:201607291253:203</DTM>
<DTM>DTM+4:201606150000:203</DTM>
<DTM>DTM+154:201608080000:203</DTM>
<RFF>RFF+CT:XXXX/0140</RFF>
<NAD>
NAD+VN++XXX HOUSE:XXXX CLOSE::XXX+XX XX XX XX LIMITED++XXX+:162::United Kingdom+XX 0XX
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+80+:::U3F36</LOC>
<CTA>CTA+CW</CTA>
<COM>COM+N/A:TE</COM>
<NAD>NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom</NAD>
<NAD>
NAD+BT++XX XX IP:XX HOUSE,:XX XX,:XX+++XX,+:162::United Kingdom+XX XXX
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+2+:::XXXXX</LOC>
<NAD>
NAD+BY++XX XX XX:XX HOUSE:XX XX:XX+++XX+:162::UnitedKingdom+XXX XXXX
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+158+:::XXXXXX</LOC>
<RFF>RFF+VA</RFF>
<CTA>CTA+OC+:XX XX</CTA>
<COM>COM+01593424302:TE</COM>
<CTA>CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) XXX</CTA>
<COM>COM+01600 711338:TE</COM>
<CUX>CUX+2:GBP</CUX>
<PAT>PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate</PAT>
<LIN>LIN+1++:VN</LIN>
<PIA>PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN</PIA>
<PIA>PIA+5+1117394:AU</PIA>
<IMD>
IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk
</IMD>
<IMD>IMD+C++:20</IMD>
<MEA>MEA+ABA+:::EACH</MEA>
<QTY>QTY+21:3:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+169:3:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+182:0:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+194:0:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+256:0:EA</QTY>
<DTM>DTM+2:201606170000:203</DTM>
<MOA>MOA+128:30.54</MOA>
<MOA>MOA+146:10.18</MOA>
<FTX>FTX+LIN</FTX>
<RFF>RFF+ON:1911677</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+FI:1/1</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+ADE:PKE00</RFF>
<NAD>
NAD+ST++XX XX XX XX:XX XX, XX XX,:XXX+++XXXX+:162::United Kingdom+XXX XXX
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+8+:::A3101A</LOC>
<CTA>CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header</CTA>
<UNS>UNS+S</UNS>
<UNT>UNT+46+02585706</UNT>
<UNH>UNH+02585706+ORDCHG:D:99B:UN</UNH>
<BGM>
BGM+230:::Purchase Order ChangeV201+1911677::0+5+AB
</BGM>
<DTM>DTM+137:201607291253:203</DTM>
<DTM>DTM+4:201606150000:203</DTM>
<DTM>DTM+154:201608080000:203</DTM>
<RFF>RFF+CT:ZZZZ/0140</RFF>
<NAD>
NAD+VN++ZZZ HOUSE:ZZZZ CLOSE::ZZZ+ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ LIMITED++ZZZ+:162::United States+ZZ 0ZZ
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+80+:::U3F36</LOC>
<CTA>CTA+CW</CTA>
<COM>COM+N/A:TE</COM>
<NAD>NAD+ST++9999++++:162::United Kingdom</NAD>
<NAD>
NAD+BT++ZZ ZZ IP:ZZ HOUSE,:ZZ ZZ,:ZZ+++ZZ,+:162::United Kingdom+ZZ ZZZ
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+2+:::ZZZZZ</LOC>
<NAD>
NAD+BY++ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ HOUSE:ZZ ZZ:ZZ+++ZZ+:162::UnitedKingdom+ZZZ ZZZZ
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+158+:::ZZZZZZ</LOC>
<RFF>RFF+VA</RFF>
<CTA>CTA+OC+:ZZ ZZ</CTA>
<COM>COM+01593424302:TE</COM>
<CTA>CTA+PD+:POWELL, WO(1,2) ZZZ</CTA>
<COM>COM+01600 711338:TE</COM>
<CUZ>CUZ+2:GBP</CUZ>
<PAT>PAT+ZZZ+7:::Immediate</PAT>
<LIN>LIN+1++:VN</LIN>
<PIA>PIA+1+1301W42151600:CG+::184+Y::52+:VN</PIA>
<PIA>PIA+5+1117394:AU</PIA>
<IMD>
IMD+F++:::Plaster Self Adhesive Blue Assorted 100/Pk
</IMD>
<IMD>IMD+C++:20</IMD>
<MEA>MEA+ABA+:::EACH</MEA>
<QTY>QTY+21:3:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+169:3:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+182:0:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+194:0:EA</QTY>
<QTY>QTY+256:0:EA</QTY>
<DTM>DTM+2:201606170000:203</DTM>
<MOA>MOA+128:30.54</MOA>
<MOA>MOA+146:10.18</MOA>
<FTZ>FTZ+LIN</FTZ>
<RFF>RFF+ON:1911677</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+FI:1/1</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+ABO:1911677/1/1</RFF>
<RFF>RFF+ADE:PKE000</RFF>
<NAD>
NAD+ST++ZZ ZZ ZZ ZZ:ZZ ZZ, ZZ ZZ,:ZZZ+++ZZZZ+:162::United Kingdom+ZZZ ZZZ
</NAD>
<LOC>LOC+8+:::A3101A</LOC>
<CTA>CTA+PD+:Requestor on Header</CTA>
<UNS>UNS+S</UNS>
<UNT>UNT+46+02585706</UNT>
</Segment>
```

The above 2 step is working only for some edi files, I am getting the same error sometime for few other edi files. Could anyone review my steps and advise me. If possible in one xquery.

Thanks
Sree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a QName can not contain whitespaces, so you should remove the whitespaces at the beginning using `fn:normalize-space()`.

Secondly, because you get the substring of your string with everything before `UNZ`, the last character of your string will be the `'`. Hence, when you later tokenize this string based on `'`, the last element of the sequence will be an empty string. You can avoid this by either cutting out the last `'` as well or you might want to check for non-empty elements. The first solution would look like this (see the `'UNZ`):

```
<Segment>{ for $id in fn:tokenize(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($body,""),"'UNZ"),"'")
     let $x := fn:normalize-space(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($id,""),"+"))
     return
     element {$x} {$id} }
    </Segment>
```

and the second one like this:

```
<Segment>{ for $id in fn:tokenize(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($body,""),"UNZ"),"'")[. != ""]
     let $x := fn:normalize-space(fn:substring-before(fn:substring-after($id,""),"+"))
     return
     element {$x} {$id} }
    </Segment>
```

Comment: Hi @dirkk, thanks for reply, I tried with normalize space, same error.

Comment: Thanks @dirrk, I tried in two steps but looking for single xquery to solve this, I have updated my question to show the 2 steps used.

Comment: thanks for your input. My data was wrong and it was giving me empty space for $x which was causing the issue of invalid QName, solved it by using if else statement and used $x only if it not empty